# How can I get to the secret in the beam room?

Tags: pid

In the room in PID where you acquire the beam, there is a bunch of stars at the very bottom. However, you can't seem to get there in obvious ways.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is missing a few blocks on the lefthand side. There are supposed to be four erasable blocks to the top left corner of the screen (as opposed to one on your screenshot) to start with. DO NOT erase them with your light source for this particular method.

Here is how to get to the part with the secret 'thumb up' constellation in the Castle Cave level. Place a vertical light source below, but to the immediate left of the aforementioned four blocks. The beam should be just tall enough for you to jump onto the platform formed by the blocks. Turn off the beam. Now *jump* and while in the air, place a new *horizontal* light source on the first vertical part of the wall above the platform. Jump into the beam. While in the beam, *jump* again and throw a second horizontal light source onto the second vertical part of the wall above the platform. This might take a few attempts to get the right distance and timing, but overall it's not that difficult. Once the second light source lands on the right surface, jump into it. Now you should be able to then hop onto the curved surface that leads to the constellation. The rest should be self-explanatory.

There was a video on Youtube that shows the exact method I described, but the account it's listed under JUST got deleted literally a few hours ago. Here is one that shows an alternate method that does not rely on the four-block platform and is VERY similar to the method that you were using in the screenshot. All credits go to the uploader of this video. Fast forward to about the 1:00 mark: